# Should I use a different email/password for Paypal's developer sandbox than my normal Paypal.com account?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm signing up for x.com (Paypal's new Developer sandbox) and am testing the API for the first time.  I already have a paypal.com account for myself and I'm writing software that I'll sell under my own name.  I don't yet have a LLC.

Should I sign up under my paypal.com account, or register a brand new one?

I'm concerned about running transactions against my personal account; and think I may also upgrade to a premier version.  One factor makes me choose an independent account; the other factor makes me opt for an integrated account.

Comment: I don't understand the -1.  This is a **developer** question that is relevant to someone getting started with Paypal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

obviously YES... if you are working on a testing mode OR testing server than you should have to create new account for testing in sandbox. because in testing its not good enough to pay from real account on live server..Its may create loss for you.

So batter way you use dummy transaction from sandbox account.

Thanks.